# How to use Lookahead on Regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a sql script to create or replace packages on oracle, and I need to check if the query is in Schema syntax like "user"."object", for instructions like Create or alter table. The regex is simple, but in the case of create Package is not so easy for me, because it can include the word "BODY" in some cases.

Suppose that my file contains the following lines (among others):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_MASSIVE_SERVICE_AUTOMIC 
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE AUTOMIC.PKG_MASSIVE_SERVICE_AUTOMIC 
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_MASSIVE_SERVICE_AUTOMIC 
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY AUTOMIC.PKG_MASSIVE_SERVICE_AUTOMIC
```

The second and the four lines are the only valid, how can I match only the *invalid* queries, i.e. lines 1 and 3?

I tried to use:

```
^CREATE\sOR\sREPLACE\sPACKAGE\s[a-zA-Z_0-9]+\s
```

But it returns:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_MASSIVE_SERVICE_AUTOMIC
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_MASSIVE_SERVICE_AUTOMIC
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY AUTOMIC.PKG_CLAUSE_TIME_V1_241_AUTOMIC
```

Then I tried to use a lookbehind"

```
CREATE\sOR\sREPLACE\sPACKAGE\s(?=BODY\s)[a-zA-Z_0-9]+\s
```

but does not work neither.

Here's an example script file:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_MASSIVE_SERVICE_AUTOMIC 
  IS
   Type REF_CUR Is Ref Cursor;

PROCEDURE PRC_GETACTIVATIONINFO_ARUS
(
    VIDACTIVACION IN NUMBER,
    RES_CURSOR OUT REF_CUR
);

PROCEDURE PRC_GETPAYMENTINFO_ARUS
(
    VIDACTIVACION IN NUMBER,
    RES_CURSOR OUT REF_CUR
);

PROCEDURE PRC_GETACTIVAPROCESSINFO_ARUS
(
    VIDACTIVACION IN NUMBER,
    RES_CURSOR OUT REF_CUR
);

PROCEDURE PRC_UPDATEPAGOS_ARUS
(
    VIDACTIVACION IN NUMBER,
    VIDPAGOSACTIVACION IN NUMBER
);
PROCEDURE PRC_GETACTPROCSBILLINGINF_ARUS
(
    VIDACTIVACION IN NUMBER,
    RES_CURSOR OUT REF_CUR
);
END;
 /
 CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_MASSIVE_SERVICE_AUTOMIC 
 IS
  PROCEDURE PRC_GETACTIVATIONINFO_ARUS
```

Comment: So `(Body )?` is optional but `AUTOMATIC.+` is required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

presuming that there is only ONE dot in the wanted line, this seems to work. [*grin*] if you have your sample lines in the variable `$InStuff`, this returns the two lines that do NOT have " Sometext." in them ...

```
$InStuff -notmatch ' [a-z]+\.'
```

output ...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_MASSIVE_SERVICE_AUTOMIC
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_MASSIVE_SERVICE_AUTOMIC
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but a more real script contains lines that not have dots.

Comment: you are most welcome [*grin*] .... but you need to provide REALISTIC samples and what the "good pattern" is. your description specified `"user"."object"` and now that is not valid. [*sigh ...*]

Comment: Hi, my mistake sorry, I already update the question with a more realistic script. thanks

Comment: @LordBacteria - you have not actually provided what was requested - and what seems _needed_ [*sigh ...*] ... several sample lines with some criteria to decide what to match/not-match.

Comment: hi, I tested again using the notmatch and  it works, thanks.

Comment: @LordBacteria - kool! you are quite welcome! glad to know you got it working as you need it ... [*grin*]

Comment: @LordBacteria: While Lee deserves kudos for providing a helpful pointer (which had my +1) _before you - regrettably belatedly - clarified your exact requirements_ , his answer currently doesn't solve your problem as  _now_ presented, so accepting it is likely to confuse future readers. Revising the answer to recommend a _two-pass_ approach - using `-match` _first_ to match `^CREATE ...` lines and _then_ excluding those _not_ containing a literal `.` via `-notmach` is a viable solution, but unless the answer actually shows that, it is not worth accepting.

Answer (score 1):

To match only `CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ...` lines where `...` does *not* contain (a literal) `.` (while being composed of letters, digits, underscores and whitespace only), you simply need to make sure that your regex matches the *full line*:

```
(Get-Content some.sql) -match '^CREATE\sOR\sREPLACE\sPACKAGE\s[\sa-z_0-9]+$'
```

Note that I've removed `A-Z`, which isn't needed, because PowerShell's `-match` operator is case-*insensitive* (`-cmatch` can be used for case-*sensitive* matching).

Answer (score 1):

Taking your question title literally, a solution with a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!.*\..*)`

With your longer sample stored in file `.\some.sql`, given that one line -  `CREATE...` - doesn't start in the 1st col without anchor `^`

```
(Get-Content .\some.sql) -match "CREATE\sOR\sREPLACE\sPACKAGE\s(BODY )?(?!.*\..*)"
```

yields this output.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_MASSIVE_SERVICE_AUTOMIC
 CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_MASSIVE_SERVICE_AUTOMIC
```